# Converting file to byte, sending it and converting it from byte array back to file

Tags: vb.net, tcp, arrays

I am trying to send a file through tcp connection in vb.net via byte array.

How do I convert the byte array back to the file and save it using savefiledialog?

The code I use to convert the file to byte array and send it is:

```
Private Sub btnfSend_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnfSend.Click
    browseFile.Title = "Browse Files"
    browseFile.InitialDirectory = "C:\Users\LF\Desktop"
    browseFile.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub browseFile_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles browseFile.FileOk
    If ((lblStatus.Text = "Status: Receiving") Or (lblStatus.Text = "Status: Connected")) Then
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = browseFile.OpenFile()
        Dim fileDir As String
        fileDir = browseFile.FileName.ToString()
        Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(fileDir)
        Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length

        Dim fStream As New FileStream(fileDir, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
        Dim data As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
        ChatSocket.SendTo(data, SocketFlags.None, New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtRemoteIP.Text), CInt(Val(txtRemotePort.Text))))
        br.Close()
        fStream.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be of some use.

Comment: But I have a chat box window the application and it uses tcp connection to send its message across. Therefore I need to differentiate between string and file.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, it sounds like you may need to send some sort of header with each message - perhaps one byte message type (e.g. 0x01 = string, 0x02 = file), followed by 4 bytes message length, followed by the data.  That can be used on the receiving end to determine what to do with the data.

Comment: I do not know how to go about doing that. I have already appended a string "File" to the front of the message but since the application deals with 1024 bytes at one time, the other parts of the file gets ignored.